# Optimal manner to calculate and store variables with multiple properties for easy retrieval

Tags: swift, macos

This is a little complicated, so if I haven't explained myself well, please ask for clarification and I'll do my best.

I need to cycle through arrays of approximately 500 objects (which are of a custom class) to calculate some statistics. Because the arrays can be quite large, I'd only want to cycle through them once for each analysis of an array, and so I really think I must do the calculations for the multiple statistics that I need in one pass.

The data I need to analyse can be of multiple states, A/B and X/Y and for each combination of those two states (AX, AY, BX, BY) I have 5 different stats I want to gather (1-5); they mostly just check for a condition and add 1 to the count. I can even reduce the stats down to 3 and have a further state to define two of them. E.g AX1 AX2* AX2** AX3* AX3** and so on.

With the current way I'm planning this, I filter down through multiple functions, and with each further function I'm able to define another state (using `enums`).

Now, my question is, what's the best way to store these statistics I'm gathering? Each statistic (could be defined nicely as a `struct`) will have at at least 2 states/properties (2 of them will have 3) so I don't want them to simply be separate variables otherwise it'll be a pain to actually use them (plus, there'll be 20 different variables). So I think I need to store them in such away that I can easily recall them using the different `enums` programmatically depending on whatever they're going to be used for. I don't think my solution lies in arrays purely for that reason, but I can't fathom a way to use dictionaries to this effect.

Does this make any sense at all or have I confused things horribly? As the day wears on my problem solving ability plummets and I fear I've made a right hash of this conundrum.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was in fact dictionaries. By using a load of enums I ended up essentially filtering down through a dictionary and at each level, adding a further property. The only downside to this is that when wanting to add a new item to the dict, you have to check every single level to see which have and haven't been created before adding your new item. The plus side is that you can programatically select the data you want without having to manually build functions for each and every possibility.